# Transductive SVM with Scikit-Learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I read in an answer [here](http://www.quora.com/Machine-Learning/How-does-one-decide-on-which-kernel-to-choose-for-an-SVM-RBF-vs-linear-vs-poly-kernel) :

> If you only have a small set of labels but lots of unlabeled data,
>   then you might try a Manifold Regularizer (i.e. Transductive SVM),
>   with or without a non-linear Kernel

Is there implementation of Transductive SVM  on Scikit-Learn ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Scikit-Learn has only the standard SVMs via Cython bindings to LibSVM

Comment: Thanks! That's why I couldn't find it. What kernal do you recommend when I have unbalanced classes.

Comment: The kernel to use is wholly data dependent, which far more factors than simply class ratio. No one can tell you what kernel to use without playing with your data.

Comment: There is an option regarding how your data is weighted within the cost function.  That is generally a much more relevant parameter when dealing with unbalanced class data.